# PHP echo variable not appearing correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following

```
 <?php echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/CAFC/images/cards/big/'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "bigcard", true).'" alt="'.the_title().'" />'; ?>
```

For some reason however my 'the_title' variable is appearing before my image when outputted as so...

```
UK Fuels Fuel Card
<img alt="" src="/wp-content/themes/CAFC/images/cards/big/ukfuels.png">
```

Can anybody give me an idea of where im going wrong?

Comment: are output buffers active? http://php.net/ob_start

Comment: Oops. Deleted my comment. Anyway, try using the standard "View source" rather than Firebug. Should show up correctly.

Comment: Also, I misunderstood your problem. Thought you were asking why "alt" was before "src".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `the_title()` auto echoes the title. Try `get_the_title()` instead.

Comment: If it's WordPress, you can pretty much assume it will auto echo. This is to make things "easy" I suppose. #dumb

Answer (score 1):

Try to use as:

```
$title = the_title();
```

and, use this `$title` in place of `the_title();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<?php echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/CAFC/images/cards/big/'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "bigcard", true).'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your browser. It changes the position of attributes for you. F. ex. Firefox can fix some HTML code according to standard.